# Excel interop string to date format

Tags: c#, datetime, formatting, excel-interop

I'm working with DataGridView and excel interop. I have access file where are column date and column time. With SQL I create new column DateTime which I then show in dgv.

```
SELECT 
    FORMAT(DateOS, 'dd.MM.yyyy') AS DateOS, 
    FORMAT(TimeOS, 'hh:mm:ss') AS TimeOS, 
    FORMAT(DateOS+TimeOS, 'dd.MM.yyyy HH:mm:ss') AS DateTimeOS 
FROM [table]
```

Then I select whole column DateTimeOS and copy it to clipboard.

After this I PasteSpecial to Excel file **which has prepared format of column**.

```
using Excel = Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel;

Excel.Workbook excelExportFile;
Excel.Worksheet wsExport;
wsExport = excelExportFile.Worksheets["Data"];

dviewAll.ColumnHeadersVisible = false;
dviewAll.SelectionMode = DataGridViewSelectionMode.FullColumnSelect;
dviewAll.Columns[columnNameDateTime].Selected = true;
DataObject data = dviewAll.GetClipboardContent();

if(data != null)
  Clipboard.SetDataObject(data, true);

dviewAll.ColumnHeadersVisible = true;
wsExport.Cells[2, 2].PasteSpecial();
```

Result is first cell is formated as string, rest is formated as datetime.

[picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PtZdO.jpg)

When I open this string cell and just press enter, it will format to datetime as rest.

Any ideas, how to prevent this issue, or how to programically open cell and press enter?

---

UPDATE:

First suggestion from [Excel treating date column as general when exporting to Excel using C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50384379/excel-treating-date-column-as-general-when-exporting-to-excel-using-c-sharp) gives me exception:

> Microsoft.CSharp.RuntimeBinder.RuntimeBinderException: 'The name
> 'Format' is bound to a method and cannot be used like a property'

And for the second one: Excel.Worksheet does not have "Column" property.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Excel treating date column as general when exporting to Excel using C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50384379/excel-treating-date-column-as-general-when-exporting-to-excel-using-c-sharp)

Comment: @Lucifer Please see my updated text above.